# How to automatically login user after cognitoUser.confirmRegistration

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

How to automatically login user once he verifies his account with the code sent to the email.

```
cognitoUser.confirmRegistration('123456', true, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                alert(err);
                return;
            }
            alert(result);
            //login User Here
        });
```

Comment: Isn't the user already logged in? You have a cognitoUser, who before calling confirmRegistration() simply has no access but is technically "logged in". Once the confirmRegistration() function succeeds, the user should have access.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Once the confirmRegistration() function succeeds, the user has no access yet. If we try this.cognitoUser.getSession, we will get the error : Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate at CognitoUser.getSession. So the user is not logged in and if we make this.pool.getCurrentUser(), the user is not logged in also.

Comment: Ah okay my mistake, I did a bit more reading and came across this, it looks like this is a known issue: https://github.com/amazon-archives/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/186

From further digging, a possible solution might be to use aws-amplify

Comment: It seems what you have to do is manually call cognitoUser.authenticateUser() after confirmRegistration() returns. See step 4 + 5: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tutorial-integrating-user-pools-javascript.html

Comment: aws-amplify@4.3.29 now has auto sign in feature https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/6320#issuecomment-1198743490